# Implementing Opencv in Iron Python Using Ironclad

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, machine-learning, iot, ironpython

Currently, I am trying to convert some scripts written in python to be able to run in Unity3d.
I came across this tutorial https://mikalikes.men/use-python-with-unity-3d-the-definitive-guide/
and the example program works fine.
However,
I ran into this error when trying to run this script with OpenCV to stream video.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;


public class StreamFromComputer: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button PIButton;
    void Start()
    {

        Button btn = PIButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(PIOnClick);

    }

    void PIOnClick()
    {
        Debug.Log("You have clicked the button!");
        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();

        ICollection<string> searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();

        //Path to the folder of greeter.py
        searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\adam\.spyder-py3");
        //Path to the Python standard library
        searchPaths.Add(@"D:\ls_alpha\AdamsPlantProcessing\Assets\Plugins\Lib");
        engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
        dynamic py = engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Users\adam\.spyder-py3\streamfrompi.py");

        Debug.Log("did that shit work");
    }
}


-------
ImportException: No module named cv2
Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions.ThrowException (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions+LightException lightEx) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions.CheckAndThrow (System.Object value) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
```

So I looked into [IRonClad](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ironclad/) but I am having trouble getting it to work in the system I am working with. I extracted to C: but when I go into my terminal > python > import ironclad I end up with

```
>>> import ironclad
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ironclad-v2.6.0rc1-bin\ironclad-v2.6.0rc1-bin\ironclad\__init__.py", line 42
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Currently, my unity 3d scene has 3 buttons, one to start the stream and one to start the camera.
I am using python for image processing and unity for UI and system deployment. I guess what I am asking is how to install it correctly so I don't receive the error. I guess I am also asking if there is a better method to go about packaging python machine learning into unity or in tandem on windows or Linux device.

---

edit/ update 9/2/2020

Currently I am at a standstill because Ironclad only works with python 2.7 not 3.7.whatever Gonna see if my whole project can be downgraded.

Comment: You could theoretically compile the IronPython code to a DLL (I'm pretty sure VS2019 can do this) and then copy that DLL to your Assets folder, so that Unity adds a reference.

Comment: I think I just might have to do that and not the lazy way I am doing currently.